# Is exponentiation in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I think the following problem belong to class P, but I don't know how I can prove it, could somebody help me?

- Inputs: two numbers $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}$
- Output: $a^b$

Comment: I don't really see the connection between your two questions, so I have removed the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not in P, for two different reasons:

1. P is a class of decision problems, but your problem is a function problem.  Instead of P, you should consider its functional equivalent FP.
2. The output could be exponentially large in the input length: encoding $b$ takes about $\log b$ bits, but encoding $a^b$ takes about $b \log a$ bits.

This still leaves open the possibility that the following problem is in P:

> Given natural numbers $a,b$ and an index $i$, determine the $i$th bit of $a^b$.

While I don't know what the answer to this question is, here is a related problem in FP:

> Given natural numbers $a,b,c$, determine $a^b \bmod c$.

This can be shown using the important technique of [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: "This still leaves open the possibility that the following problem is in P: Given natural numbers $a,b$ and an index $i$, determine the $i$th bit of $a^b$". This is not open, and is in $P$ by your problem in FP: Given natural numbers $a,b,c$, determine $a^b\ \mathrm{mod}\ c$ and set $c=2^i$

Comment: Also, if $i$ is the index from the left (more significant digit, in **big endian**), then a careful base conversion that involves floating-point arithmetics could determine the number of bits in binary representation of $a^b$.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, since $2^i$ is not polynomial in $i$.

Comment: OK, my bad. So, all that we can do is to extract polynomially many least significant bits of $a^b$.